# Using a EF Repository with custom connection objects?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am stuck in EF 6 and the documentation is sparse - not getting that solved for a day now.

I try to use Code First on a database repository we have. Due to complex initialization I *must* use my own factory method to initialize the context subclass and I *must* put my own sql connection in, or make my own factory.

THe following class initialization:

we have:

```
public class Repository : DbContext {

static string _connectionString;

    static Repository() {
        Database.SetInitializer<Repository>(null);
        var type = typeof(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices);
        _connectionString = ** method to get connection string**
    }

    public static Repository Create() {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted).Commit();
        return new Repository(connection);
    }
```

Sadly running it blows with the following exception on the first attempt to select some entity:

Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

I am totally out of my mind how to fix that.

My config file in the using web application reads:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0" />
    </providers>   
</entityFramework>
```

Anyone can tell me how to fix that? My alternative is to move back to model first - but I would really like to give code first a try here.

Comment: Same type of error is fixed in this solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903037/entity-framework-profiler-asp-net-mvc4-with-ef-6-unable-to-determine-the-prov

Comment: @Bharadwaj Interesting enough not. As the answer there is that it was a bug in the profiler... which i do not even use.

Comment: This must be in the details of how you create the connection string. What do you need the type `SqlProviderServices` for?

Comment: Which exact EF version are you using? Can your post your Repository's `Repository(connection)` constructor?

Comment: (Regardless of connection string in you code) Do you have something like that in your connection strings? There is also provider that you should set. `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Repository " 
         connectionString="connectionString" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirements for my projects: EF repositories had to accept connection instances created from my own factory. To that end I chose to completely ignore the EF config file scheme. Instead, I did the following:

```
public class Repository : DbContext
{
    static Repository ()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Repository>(null);
    }

    public Repository(SqlConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // creating the model myself
    }
    // (...)
}
```

Since it can accept connection instances from the outside I'm free to use whatever connection factory I want and completely ignore EF's config file scheme.

If you want your connection factory inside the repository (which I don't recommend for the sake of separating concerns), you could add the following to the above:

```
public Repository()
    : base(CreateConnection(), true)
{
}

private static SqlConnection CreateConnection()
{
    // do whatever you have to do to create your SqlConnection instance, using your own rules
}
```