# Accessing EF6 in code throws System.NotSupportedException in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, entity-framework-6

based on .NET 4.0 and EF 6.1, I've created a project names Database with an Entity Model to access a SQL Server instance via Designer in Visual Studio 2013.
Additionally, there is an Console Application (also .NET 4.0) trying to consume the entities of the Database-project.

The credentials for the underlying database are stored in the Console Application's App.config within the key `<connectionStrings>`.
When creating a DbContext in the following way, I can perfectly access the entities:

```
var db = new MyEntities();
var o1 = db.Buildings.First();
```

MyEntities is the class that the Entity Framework creates automatically, inheriting from `DbContext`.
For some compatibility reasons to our guidelines, I'm trying to split up the `connectionString` into own keys (`database`, `instance`, `user`, `password`) within Ap.config.
For this, I'm using `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` to build up the `EntityConnection` with `ProviderConnectionString`, `Metadata` and `Provider`. It look's like this:

```
Dim sqlBuilder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = True
sqlBuilder.DataSource = "database instance"
sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "database"
sqlBuilder.UserID = "user"
sqlBuilder.Password = "password"

Dim providerConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString()

Dim metaData = @"res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl"

Dim entityConnectionBuilder As New EntityConnectionStringBuilder() With { _
  .Metadata = metaData, _
  .ProviderConnectionString = providerConnectionString, _
  .Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient"}

Dim s = entityConnectionBuilder.ToString()
entityConnection = New EntityConnection(s)
```

In my Console Application, I call:

```
var db1 = new MyEntities(entityConnection);
var o2 = db1.Buildings.First();
```

When executing the last line, the following exception will be thrown:
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
Additional information: Unable to determine the DbProviderFactory type for connection of type 'System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.**

App.config of Console Application contains the following:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas, why this exception occurs?

Comment: What's your context look like? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578091/using-a-ef-repository-with-custom-connection-objects

Comment: The `DbContext` class hasn't been changed by me, so it's the default generated by EF

Comment: Are there no other ideas?

Comment: Show your DbContext and constructor. My constructor is public ApplicationDbContext() : base("myWebConfigConnectionStringName") {}  Also, check your /bin folder and make sure EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll is in there.

Comment: I also have a constructor like yours, but I don't want to use it since I wan't to pass my own connection. Anyway, the constructors look like this:  Public Sub New(dbConnection As DbConnection, Optional disposeConnection As Boolean = True)
        MyBase.New(dbConnection, disposeConnection)
    End Sub  Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("name=<<The connection string within App.config>>")
    End Sub